# Adding an ID or Class in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got the following code for a search form, but how would I add an ID or a class to the submit button?

```
<% form_tag '/wine/search/', :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= label_tag "Search" %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search_string, params[:search_string] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
submit_tag "Go", :class => "some_class"
submit_tag "Go", :id=> "some_id"
```

From the [Rails API FormTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001739)